# Leaflet Shiny: Points data not found

Tags: shiny, leaflet

I am trying to plot circles on leaflet following the example given in RSTUDIO'S github page [here.](http://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/shiny.html)  I have been trying to get it work for the last couple of days be adopting various suggestions given here as well as in other blogs.  But I am getting the following error constantly:

```
Warning: Error in derivePoints: Point data not found; please provide addCircles with data and/or lng/lat arguments
```

I am not sure if I am missing any libraries or if any of my packages requires update. The following is the data set along with the codes.  If I run the example as is from the r-studio's github page, it runs without any issues.  I check the structure of the data, and both are exactly the same types.  Not sure where the issue could be:

Desired output:  A map with differential sized circles for each category (cereals, pulses) which reactively changes upon selection.

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(RColorBrewer)

data <- structure(list(LATITUDE = c(26.912434, 28.459497, 23.022505, 
10.790483, 28.704059), LONGITUDE = c(75.787271, 77.026638, 72.571362, 
78.704673, 77.10249), CEREALS = c(450L, 350L, 877L, 1018L, 600L
), PULSES = c(67L, 130L, 247L, 250L, 324L)), .Names = c("LATITUDE", 
"LONGITUDE", "CEREALS", "PULSES"), row.names = c(1263L, 4524L, 
10681L, 7165L, 12760L), class = "data.frame")

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  tags$style(type = "text/css", "html, body {width:100%;height:100%}"),
  leafletOutput("map", width = "100%", height = "100%"),
  absolutePanel(top = 10, right = 10,
    selectInput(inputId = "productCategoryMonthly", "PRODUCTS",choices = NULL, selected = NULL),
      selectInput("colors", "Color Scheme",rownames(subset(brewer.pal.info, category %in% c("seq", "div")))
    )))


server <- function(input, output, session) {

    df <- reactive({data})    

    observe({
        withProgress(message = "Loading data, Please wait...",value = 0.1, {
        updateSelectizeInput(session,inputId = "productCategoryMonthly", choices = as.character(sort(toupper(colnames(df()[,c(3:4)]))),decreasing = TRUE), selected = "CEREALS", server = TRUE)
        })
    })

  filteredData <- reactive({
        if(input$productCategoryMonthly == "CEREALS") {
            df()[,c(1,2,3)]
        } else if (input$productCategoryMonthly == "PULSES") {
                df()[,c(1,2,4)]
        } 
  })

  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(df()) %>% addTiles() %>%
      fitBounds(~min(LONGITUDE), ~min(LATITUDE), ~max(LONGITUDE), ~max(LATITUDE))
  })


  observe({
    mag <- filteredData()[[input$productCategoryMonthly]]
    leafletProxy("map", data = filteredData()) %>%
      clearShapes() %>%
      addCircles(radius = ~10^mag/10, weight = 1, color = "#777777",
        fillOpacity = 0.7, popup = ~paste(mag)
      )
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit modified code:

I have rescaled the mag variable to control the circle sizes, you might want to play with that so that the circle area represent the quantities regardless of the product category. I have hard-coded the product drop-down, the dynamic creation of the dropdown does not work. Will take a look at that later. The fill color was missing in the leafletProxy call. 
This is the code:

```
library(shiny)
    library(leaflet)
    library(RColorBrewer)



    data <- structure(list(LATITUDE = c(26.912434, 28.459497, 23.022505, 
                                        10.790483, 28.704059), 
                           LONGITUDE = c(75.787271, 77.026638, 72.571362, 
                                                                             78.704673, 77.10249), 
                           CEREALS = c(450L, 350L, 877L, 1018L, 600L
                                                                             ), 
                           PULSES = c(67L, 130L, 247L, 250L, 324L)), 
                      .Names = c("LATITUDE", "LONGITUDE", "CEREALS", "PULSES"), 
                      row.names = c(1263L, 4524L, 10681L, 7165L, 12760L), 
                      class = "data.frame")
    #mag <- c(5, 5.2, 5.3, 5.4, 5.5)

    ui <- bootstrapPage(
            tags$style(type = "text/css", "html, body {width:100%;height:100%}"),
            leafletOutput("map", width = "100%", height = "100%"),
            absolutePanel(top = 10, right = 10,
                          selectInput(inputId = "productCategoryMonthly", "PRODUCTS",choices = c("CEREALS", "PULSES"), selected = NULL),
                          selectInput("colors", "Color Scheme",rownames(subset(brewer.pal.info, category %in% c("seq", "div")))
                          )))

    server <- function(input, output, session) {

            df <- reactive({data})    

            # observe({
            #         withProgress(message = "Loading data, Please wait...",value = 0.1, {
            #                 updateSelectInput(session,inputId = "productCategoryMonthly", choices = as.character(sort(toupper(colnames(df()[,c(3:4)]))),decreasing = TRUE), selected = "CEREALS", server = TRUE)
            #         })
            # })

            filteredData <- reactive({
                    if(input$productCategoryMonthly == "CEREALS") {
                            df()[,c(1,2,3)]
                    } else if (input$productCategoryMonthly == "PULSES") {
                            df()[,c(1,2,4)]
                    } 
            })
            mag <- reactive({
                    if(input$productCategoryMonthly == "CEREALS") {
                            mag <- (filteredData()[[input$productCategoryMonthly]]/sum(filteredData()[[input$productCategoryMonthly]])) + 5       
                    } else if (input$productCategoryMonthly == "PULSES") {
                            mag <- (filteredData()[[input$productCategoryMonthly]]/sum(filteredData()[[input$productCategoryMonthly]])) + 5 
                    }    
                    mag
            })

            output$map <- renderLeaflet({
                    leaflet(df()) %>% addTiles() %>%
                            fitBounds(~min(LONGITUDE), ~min(LATITUDE), ~max(LONGITUDE), ~max(LATITUDE))
            })

            colorpal <- reactive({
                    colorNumeric(input$colors, filteredData()[[3]])
            })
            observe({
                    pal <- colorpal()
                    #mag <- filteredData()[[input$productCategoryMonthly]]^(1/4)
                    leafletProxy("map", data = filteredData()) %>%
                            clearShapes() %>%
                            addCircles(radius = ~10^mag()/10, weight = 1, color = "#777777", fillColor = ~pal(filteredData()[[3]]),
                                       fillOpacity = 0.7, popup = ~paste(mag())
                            )
            })

    }

    shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Beakovic  Many many thanks...truly appreciate.....have been going bonkers over it for last two days almost....I have tried almost every possible combination...including using the mag value as is....still couldn't get it....I could have never thought of the tweak in rescaling the values....no problems with the drop down...it works in my original version.  Many thanks again.